# How do I refer to tables in a trigger? / OR / How do I look up FK values to be added on insert automatically?

Tags: oracle, trigger

My goal is to have Oracle fill in FK values that correspond to the right PK values of a parent table.

I have this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER connect_purified_enz_to_produced
    BEFORE INSERT ON purified_enz
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SELECT produced.produced_id
        INTO :NEW.g_id
    FROM produced 
        JOIN pur_connector ext
            ON produced.construct_id = ext.construct_id
               AND produced.g_batch = ext.g_batch
    WHERE produced.produced_id = :NEW.purified_enz_id;
END;
```

This is my insert statement:

```
INSERT 
INTO purified_enz p
    (
    p.p_batch,
    p.final_buffer_system,
    p.buffer_mol,
    p.final_nacl,
    p.final_ph,
    p.final_add,
    p.yield,
    p.concentration ) 
SELECT  
    p_batch,    
    final_buffer_system,
    buffer_mol,
    final_nacl,
    final_ph,
    final_add,
    yield,
    concentration 
FROM EXTERNAL ((
  construct_id NUMBER(10),
  n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
  enz_name VARCHAR2 (50),
  c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
  cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
  mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
  g_batch VARCHAR2 (50),
  emptycol VARCHAR2(1),
  purified_enz_id VARCHAR2 (50),
  g_id VARCHAR2 (50),
  p_batch VARCHAR2 (50),
  final_buffer_system VARCHAR2 (50),
  buffer_mol NUMBER (6, 2),
  final_nacl NUMBER (4),
  final_ph NUMBER (4, 2),
  final_add VARCHAR2 (50),
  yield NUMBER (6, 2),
  concentration NUMBER (6, 2))

    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        SKIP 1
        BADFILE bad_files:'badflie_insert_into_purified_enz_from_purified_enz.bad'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('PURIFIED_ENZ.CSV')
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED) ext
 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM construct c INNER JOIN produced pr
        ON c.construct_id = pr.construct_id
        INNER JOIN purified_enz p
        ON pr.produced_id = p.g_id 
        
            WHERE c.construct_id = ext.construct_id
            AND c.n_term = ext.n_term
            AND c.enz_name = ext.enz_name
            AND c.c_term = ext.c_term
            AND c.cpp = ext.cpp
            AND c.mutations = ext.mutations
            AND pr.g_batch = ext.g_batch
        );
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "C##ELLIE.CONNECT_PURIFIED_ENZ_TO_PRODUCED", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'C##ELLIE.CONNECT_PURIFIED_ENZ_TO_PRODUCED'
```

The insert statement works if the trigger doesn't exist.

---

This is my attempt at using lookup.

```
CREATE TABLE lookup_pufiried_FK NOLOGGING PARALLEL AS SELECT
FK_for_purified_enz, ext.g_batch, ext.p_batch 

FROM pur_connector ext INNER JOIN produced pr
ON pr.construct_id = ext.construct_id
AND pr.g_batch = ext.g_batch

WHERE FK_for_purified_enz = pr.produced_id;
```

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/loading-transformation-date-warehouses.html#GUID-F03860DA-EE32-46EF-A670-D6E7DE037669) says that a table created in the format `WHERE X = Y` should convert an X value into a Y value. I don't have a valid `purified_enz` value in the external table. I just have 2 values that can be used to identify which PK each record corresponds to if you do some joins. So idk if this is even the right approach.

Error:

```
WHERE FK_for_purified_enz = pr.produced_id
Error report -
ORA-00904: "FK_FOR_PURIFIED_ENZ": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

---

SOLVED:

So, I have finally figured out that I need two staging tables.

```
CREATE TABLE purified_enz_stage1
    (
      construct_id NUMBER(10),
      n_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      enz_name VARCHAR2 (50),
      c_term VARCHAR2 (50),
      cpp VARCHAR2 (50),
      mutations VARCHAR2 (50),
      g_batch VARCHAR2 (50),
      emptycol VARCHAR2(50),
      purified_enz_id VARCHAR2 (50),
      g_id VARCHAR2 (50),
      p_batch VARCHAR2 (50),
      final_buffer_system VARCHAR2 (50),
      buffer_mol NUMBER (6, 2),
      final_nacl NUMBER (4),
      final_ph NUMBER (4, 2),
      final_add VARCHAR2 (50),
      yield NUMBER (6, 2),
      concentration NUMBER (6, 2))
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY data_to_input
    ACCESS PARAMETERS (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
        SKIP 1
        BADFILE bad_files:'badflie_insert_into_pur_connector_from_purified_enz.bad'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL 
        ) 
    LOCATION ('PURIFIED_ENZ.CSV')
    ) REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

CREATE TABLE purified_enz_stage2 AS SELECT

      ext.construct_id,
      ext.n_term,
      ext.enz_name,
      ext.c_term,
      ext.cpp,
      ext.mutations,
      ext.g_batch,
      ext.emptycol,
      ext.purified_enz_id,
      ext.g_id,
      ext.p_batch,
      ext.final_buffer_system,
      ext.buffer_mol,
      ext.final_nacl,
      ext.final_ph,
      ext.final_add,
      ext.yield,
      ext.concentration,
      pr.produced_id 

FROM purified_enz_stage1 ext INNER JOIN produced pr
ON pr.construct_id = ext.construct_id
AND pr.g_batch = ext.g_batch;
```

And then I just import from staging table 2!

```
INSERT 
INTO purified_enz
    (
    g_id,
    p_batch,
    final_buffer_system,
    buffer_mol,
    final_nacl,
    final_ph,
    final_add,
    yield,
    concentration ) 
SELECT  
    produced_id,
    p_batch,    
    final_buffer_system,
    buffer_mol,
    final_nacl,
    final_ph,
    final_add,
    yield,
    concentration 
FROM purified_enz_stage2;
```

Comment: `produced` is not visible in `SET g_id = produced.produced_id`. There are other problems with your query as well. I suggest you add create table statements as well as insert statements for som sample data that illustrates the problem.

Comment: @Lennart this is actually a  [duplicate] (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273609/making-a-trigger-to-update-fk-based-on-columns-in-another-table-and-an-external). My original question has more info, but no one responded, so I thought I'd isolate the part I care about the most. Is any of that information helpful? I can add create table statements, but I don't know what the problem is. I guess my question is more "how do i make a trigger?". I can't find any examples where people use a join to do what I'm doing inside a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

It was too complicated writing in a comment, so I'll do a sketch as an answer. I don't know Oracle, but if it resembles other DBMS something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER connect_purified_enz_to_produced
    BEFORE INSERT ON purified_enz
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SELECT produced.produced_id
        INTO :NEW.g_id
    FROM produced 
        JOIN pur_connector ext
            ON produced.construct_id = ext.construct_id
               AND produced.g_batch = ext.g_batch
    WHERE <what?> = :NEW.purified_enz_id;
END;
```

I did not fully understand how produced, pur_connector, and purified_enz relate, but hopefully, it will give you some idea.

Comment: ! 1) Your code helped me write a trigger that actually compiled! Thank you! 2) The join you wrote perfectly captures the relationship between those three tables. 3) But I get an error when I use the trigger... I'll update my question with it. Also, why did you use before insert and not after? (It doesn't work with before insert either.)

Comment: Since you are just modifying the row that is about to be inserted, there is no need for an after trigger.

Comment: would it make a difference if my insert statement has a `WHERE NOT EXISTS ` clause that performs a join. I use this to make sure I don't insert duplicates. Would that clause get executed before the trigger? Also, it appears that the error i'm getting happens when "a row-level trigger attempts to read or write the table from which the trigger was fired". So i'm gonna learn how one is supposed to update a table without having a trigger on that table. (http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html)

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate? Usually a UNIQUE constraint is used to prevent that

Comment: if my unique constraint is `column_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,` that would be a unique ID, but if i insert 10 duplicates of the same thing, they'll all get unique IDs and be considered 10 different records. If I don't generate a unique ID automatically, I would have to manually give each record I insert a unique ID. Which is a recipe for disaster. If i have 500 records, how should i check if the one i'm inserting is not a duplicate? Am I wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63201257/how-can-i-load-only-unique-data-into-my-oracle-table-without-specifying-pk-manua

Comment: oh also. when I made this database, my unique constraint is in the `purified_enz` table is `CONSTRAINT uq_purified_enz UNIQUE (g_id, p_batch)`. Which depends on the `g_id` which is the FK that refers to its parent table's PK. But it would be impractical for me to manually search the entire parent table in a CSV and manually copy and paste the corresponding value into the FK of the `purified_enz` table. Which is why i'm trying to write a trigger to automate it.

Comment: @ellie-lumen - I recommend that you don't put the "lookup FK value" function inside a trigger.  Put that functionality inside your `INSERT .. SELECT` statement.

Comment: @MichaelKutz can you show me what you mean please? (I'm super new to this so its not obvious). Also, I see you all over dba questions here, so i feel like i'm speaking straight to a dba wizard! Maybe that's normal on SE. Would it be too off-topic or broad to ask why you can't select from and update the same table with a trigger? I'm reading this http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html and I don't understand why this is a problem. Are triggers just not meant to be used to change any information? (Or should I post this as a separate question?)

Comment: This would be better in Chat.  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111769/discussion-with-ellie-lumen (I think you need 20 pts to participate; if its 200 pts, I'll drop the room)